# Fatou's Lemma - discrete case : examples correct?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

In our homework for measure theory, we are asked to provide examples for (1) equality, (2) strict inequality, and (3) violations of the inequality for a negative case. We are given $(\Omega = \mathbb{N}, \mathcal{A} = \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{\mathbb{N}}), \mu(\{k\}) = \frac{1}{2^k})$, $k = 1, 2, \dots$.

So I was wondering whether my reasoning is correct.

For (1) I set $f_n = 1$, then $\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}f_n = 1$ and $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty } f_n = 1$, so $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}= 1$; and also $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^\infty f^n\frac{1}{2^k} = 1$.

Regarding (2) I have a problem. Can I have $n$ equal to $k$? If so, I would argue that when $f^k = \frac{1}{k}$, the LHS of Fatou's Lemma becomes $0$, as $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{k} = \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{k} = 0$ while on the RHS  we will ultimately endy up with $\infty$.

As to (3) just multiply an $f^n$ from (2) by $-1$.

Thank you, as always, for any sort of input.

Comment: You are trying to come up with examples for equality, strict inequality and also show that this lemma doesn’t hold for a sequence of non-positive functions? Can you work with the version for Lebesgue integrals: $$\int_E \liminf(f_n) dm \leq \liminf \int_E f_ndm?$$

Comment: Yes, when $\Omega = [0, 1]$ and we use Borel sets and the Lebesgue measure, I have already solved the problem or found solutions.

Comment: All right then.

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding something? Given this measure space, the integrals should be replaced with with sums, shouldn't they?

Comment: You could replace them with sums, but it's better to leave them as integrals to connect with Fatou. (By the way, for 1. you could just define everything to be $0.$)

Comment: Yes, this I thought of too. But how would I integrate over a function using this measure?

Comment: Like you said, they turn out to be the obvious sums. Sure, use sums in evaluating the integrals, you know, $\int_{\mathbb N} f\, d\mu = \sum_n f(n)/2^n$ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for 2: Try $f_n = 2^n\chi_{\{n\}} \,\,(= 2^n \mathbf{1}_{\{n\}}).$

Comment: Ahhhhh, thanks @zhw. So on the LHS, this turns out to be $1$, because we have $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^n_{\chi \{n\}} = 2$, and hence $2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} = 1$. On the RHS, the sum diverges to infinity. So we have strict inequality. This should be it, shouldn't it?

Comment: Well ... no. $\liminf f_n = 0$ so on the LHS you get $\int_{\mathbb N}0\,d\mu = 0.$ On the RHS we get  $\liminf \int_{\mathbb N}f_n\,d\mu = \liminf 1 = 1.$ It will be good for you to get these things down, as building examples in measure theory increases one's intuition.

Comment: Yes, I will certainly take up that advice! I see my error on the RHS clearly. How careless! But I always thought that the $\liminf$ is defined as the greatest lower bound, it turns out to be $0$ if $n \rightarrow  - \infty$. But aren't we restricted to the realm of natural numbers here?

Comment: Sorry if my questions may strike you as rather uninitiated or naive.

Comment: No need to apologize, this is fine. I'm just encouraging you to spend time on this example, because similar things will occur elsewhere. No, the $\liminf$ is not the glb, it is the limit of the glbs. Do you see that the pointwise limit of $f_n$ is $0$ everywhere?

Comment: So I looked it up: $f(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$ is defined as the pointwise limit of $f_n$.  Ahhh so we have $f_n = 2^n$, for $i = n$, and $f_n = 0$, otherwise. Yes, I agree that analysis is something to be thoroughly mastered.

Comment: Yes, I was thrown of the scent by the use of $\chi$ as representing the indicator function, although I even read it in the first chapter of Halmos' book. I just leave this here for future reference.